# Adapter & ListView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to get list. Each line - mas[i]. Numb - it's int.
I got an eclipse error:

> The constructor ArrayAdapter(new View.OnClickListener(){},
>   int, String[]) is undefined

```
 public class FirstActivity extends ListActivity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView NumbZK = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);   
            final int Numb = Integer.parseInt(NumbZK.getText().toString()); 

            TextView modN = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1); 
            final int N = Integer.parseInt(modN.getText().toString());  

            String[] mas = new String[N];
            for (int i=0; i<N;i++){
                mas[i]=Integer.toString(Numb%(i+1));
            }
            ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mas));


        }
    });
 }
}
```

XML:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />
```

help

Comment: Can you give us your xml? It's easier to see the problem

Comment: </LinearLayout>
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />

Comment: 10-25 09:49:53.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14724): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bla/com.bla.FirstActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:id="@+id/lView"
```

Since that's what your looking for in your activity.

Comment: It is, if you are extending Activity and not ListActivity! I've done this before many times.

Comment: I'm sure he is extending ListActivity since that's the error he's getting: 'your content must have a listview whose id attribute is 'android.r.id.list'

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Answer (score 2):

If your `Activity` is extending from `ListActivity` you need to declare a `ListView` with `android:id="@android:id/list"` in your layout. Then you can get the `ListView` by calling `getListView()` in your `Activity`

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: Like this?--------
  
ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
          lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mas));

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    />

---------
get eclipse err: The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, String[]) is undefined

Comment: You are getting another unrelated error now, edit your question and add more code.

Comment: It seems you are running that code inside a onClickListener? Why is that?

Comment: Because I need to do this after I press the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
mas[i]=""+(Numb%(i+1));
```

consider replacing the above line with

```
mas[i] = "" + Integer.toString(Numb%(i+1));
```

after looking at your xml,

```
ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lView);
```

replace this with

```
ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

and also

```
lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mas));
```

with

```
lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(youractivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mas));
```

this should be replaced by context , this method will not work for onclicklistener.

HTH.

Comment: You can just use getListView() instead of looking for the view by id.

Comment: Only if it's a `ListActivity`.

Comment: done, but now had eclipse err: The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, String[]) is undefined

Comment: check my edited answer, it is problem with the 1st argument "this", you should put the context of the activity in it. accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Oh, it's work. But now got previous err in logcat: 10-25 11:50:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14950): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bla/com.bla.FirstActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Answer (score -1):

Try adding:

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/lView/>
```

In the layout file